# playing of .wav file

Tags: c#, soundplayer

I am making a piano app, where each key plays a different `.wav` file. For instance, if the `C` note is pressed then `C.wav` is played.

So far I have only managed to play a wav file using the code in the screenshot, otherwise the file is not found. However this method is not suitable for what I am trying to do. The wav file i am trying to play is called `hello.wav` and I have provided the location. Any suggestions?

This is the current code:

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(PianoApp.Properties.Resources.Hello);
sp.Play();
```

or as it appears in my IDE:

[image: current code]

This is the file location:

[image: file location]

Comment: The code should be posted as a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I,

Add you your file .wav in ressource of your project with mySoundFile as name, and code like this

```
 Stream str = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile;
 SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(str);
 snd.Play();
```

with multiple .wav ressources

```
 Stream str1 = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile1;
 Stream str2 = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile2;

 RecordPlayer rp = new RecordPlayer();
 rp.Open(new WaveReader(str1));
 rp.Play();

 rp.Open(new WaveReader(str2));
 rp.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to find your files in the output folder of your application, then just set the "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy always" in the Properties window.
But if you want to keep them in resources, then you can also use `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("audioResourceName")` to get your audio files according to a particular key name that was pressed. Thus, you should name all your resources accordingly.